# $(n+1)^3x_{n+1}=2n^2(2n+1)x_{n}+2(3n+1)$ find $x_n$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $(x_{n})$ be a sequence

$x_0=1$

$(n+1)^3x_{n+1}=2n^2(2n+1)x_{n}+2(3n+1)$

Find $x_n$

Please give me some hints

Answer (score 2):

A small hint that should get you started : let us compute a few first terms :

$$
x_2=\frac{7}{4}, \ x_3=\frac{28}{9}, x_4=\frac{103}{16}, \ldots 
$$

Looks like the denominator is $n^2$. So let us put $y_n=(n^2)x_n$.
Then $(y_n)$ satisfies

$$
(n+1)y_n=2(2n+1)y_n+2(3n+1)
$$

Comment: Why not we put $y_n=n^2x_n-2$ so we have $(n+1)y_{n+1}=2(3n+1)y_n$

And... (i don't know)

Comment: @tangkhaihanh  You’re on the right tack! You should find a way to write your $y_n$ (or something closely related) as a product.

Comment: Can we use induction?, Can you write more detail?